# R CMD build leaves compiled .o files in src folder

Tags: r, cran

I am one of the author of the R package [xgboost](https://github.com/tqchen/xgboost/tree/master/R-package). When I tried to pack it with `R CMD build xgboost`, there are 5 new compiled `.o` files inside `src/`.

I double checked that these files are not in the directory before. And strangely, this problem disappears when I run `R CMD build --no-build-vignettes xgboost`. I suspect there are something related to the process of compiling the vignettes. However we don't want to sacrifice the vignettes for it.

How can this be fixed? Thanks!

NOTE: To reproduce the problem, please run the following command in your console:

`git clone https://github.com/tqchen/xgboost && cd xgboost && make Rpack`

where `make Rpack` is a combination of file operations that move files to the correct places and `R CMD` operations. Edit the `Rpack` part in `Makefile` to control this flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after some attempts the following solution works for me:

1. Create a file named `.Rbuildignore`
2. Fill it with the file names (patterns) that you don't need.

An example is this file: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/R-package/.Rbuildignore